# Make .vimrc discriminate against filetype or working directory?

Tags: vim

I wasn't really sure how to search for this topic, so I hope that this is an original question.

## Context

When I code in vim, I like to `set number` (I have placed it in my `.vimrc`), but when I view my markdown file of personal links (to recipes etc.), I do not need `set number`, but do not want to always type `set nonumber`.

## Question

Is there a way to have `set number` (or other properties for that matter) toggle on or off based on filetype or the directory that is being worked in (a type of whitelist or blacklist)?

## Edit

I just found the `autocmd Filetype setlocal ...` option, but `autocmd Filetype setlocal set nonumber` does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You need the pattern for the `autocmd`. Since you are using the `FileType` event the pattern will be matching against the `'filetype'`.

```
augroup my_ft
  autocmd!
  autocmd FileType markdown setlocal nonumber
augroup END
```

You can also add `set nonumber` in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/markdown.vim`.